# What's the different between PhantomData<Box<Node<T>>> and PhantomData<T>

Tags: rust

Rust `LinkedList` contains one marker field: `PhantomData<Box<Node<T>>>`.

```
pub struct LinkedList<T> {
   head: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
   tail: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
   len: usize,
   marker: PhantomData<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct Node<T> { 
  next: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>, 
  prev: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>, 
  element: T, 
}
```

From https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html. `PhantomData` is for two purpose: variance & dropchk.

I already read https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0769-sound-generic-drop.html and https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1238-nonparametric-dropck.html, but did not fully understand it.

What's the differece between `PhantomData<Box<Node<T>>>`, `PhantomData<Node<T>>` and `PhantomData<T>`?

Comment: Seems like we'd need to know what `Node` is to answer this.

Comment: Beyond drop behavior and variance, `PhantomData` also affects auto trait implementation such as `Send`, `Sync`, and `Unpin`

Comment: In this case it looks like a drop checker thing: we are telling the drop checker that dropping a `LinkedList<T>` might result in dropping a `Box<Node<T>>`. Whether that's the same as dropping a `T` or dropping a `Node<T>` depends on the definitions of `Node` and `Box`, but there is no harm in playing it safe and telling the compiler exactly what it is you are dropping.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, You can check the source code in linked_list.rs which is from rust-src. Node definition is: 
   struct Node<T> {
    next: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
    prev: Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>,
    element: T,
}

Comment: @user4815162342, is that to say - no difference whatever it is? Box<Node\<T\>>, Node\<T\> and T all works?

Comment: @trentcl, from rust-src and docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/boxed/struct.Box.html, https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/struct.PhantomData.html. Box and Node does no customized Send/Sync/Unpin, it depends on T.

Comment: @user3093762 I didn't say that there was no difference, but that the difference depends on the drop semantics of `Node` and `Box`. If the code is dropping a `Box<Node<T>>`, it makes sense that it contains a `PhantomData<Box<Node<T>>`. Using just `PhantomData<T>` *might* produce the same effect regarding drop checking, but why risk it?